# PHP 7 Xdebug in VSCODE: how to ignore exceptions

Tags: php, exception, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm using plugin PHP Debugger in Visual Studio Code to debug PHP codes.
All were ok with PHP <= 5.6. The debugger worked like a charm.
But when I try to debug the code with PHP 7, it does not work as expected.
It does not jump to the break points I added, I was stuck at thounsand excepton like

> Exception has occurred. Deprecated: Methods with the same name as
>   their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP;
>   RecurringType has a deprecated constructor

Or

> Exception has occurred. Warning: Declaration of AntlrLexer::matchAny()
>   should be compatible with BaseRecognizer::matchAny($input)

Or

> Exception has occurred. Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

These exception are generated by the Framework so I can not fix them all, I just want to skip all these exceptions and jump to my break points only.

How can I achieve that?
Thanks.

Comment: Framework is working with PHP 7?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Ofcouse. It's vTiger 7.1.0

Answer (score 39):

I don't know if this will work with your configuration (I'm using PHP 7.2 with WordPress), and have found this works to keep XDebug from triggering every Exception, Warning, Notice, etc. if I just want to step through my own sections of code.

First, uncheck everything (including `Everything`, if checked) in the `Breakpoints` debug section:

[image: XDebug Breakpoints]

Then hover over the `Breakpoints` bar and click the `+`:

[image: Breakpoint bar - Add Function]

Now add the name of a function you want to debug:

[image: Add breakpoint function]

Finally, set a breakpoint within that function. You will now be able to trigger an XDebug step-through only within that function:

[image: Stepping through an XDebug session without triggering every exception]

You can, presumably, add as many of your own function breakpoints as you want. An interesting aside is that if you have multiple functions with the same name, you only have to add the function name once.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. My problem is the Everything line is automatically checked then it stuck with thousand of notice and warning of the framework :)

Answer (score 5):

In my case the extension or editor came with the EVERYTHING option checked by default. Unchecking EVERYTHING checkbox fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

### Problem

It sounds like the framework you are using was written with a pre PHP 7 version in mind. Error handling has [changed](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php) and now an unhandled exception or `Throwable` instance, to be more accurate, will bubble up to the exception handling function defined with the [set_exception_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) function. The bigger problem is a **FATAL ERROR** means *bang bang, process is dead* and nothing for the debugger to bind to.

> PHP 7 changes how most errors are reported by PHP. Instead of reporting errors through the traditional error reporting mechanism used by PHP 5, most errors are now reported by throwing [Error exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php).
>
> As with normal exceptions, these Error exceptions will bubble up until they reach the first matching catch block. If there are no matching blocks, then any default exception handler installed with set_exception_handler() will be called, and if there is no default exception handler, then the exception will be converted to a fatal error and will be handled like a traditional error.
>
> As the Error hierarchy does not inherit from Exception, code that uses catch (Exception $e) { ... } blocks to handle uncaught exceptions in PHP 5 will find that these Errors are not caught by these blocks. Either a catch (Error $e) { ... } block or a set_exception_handler() handler is required>.

---

### Solution

So how can you skip over all these errors (which are being converted to fatal errors and stopping execution) and allow it to reach your breakpoint? By defining an error handler with `set_exception_handler()`.

Inject something like this in your framework bootstrapping code. Be sure to look for anywhere that the framework might override this.

```
function ignore_exceptions_handler($exception) {
   // Do nothing here
}

set_exception_handler('ignore_exceptions_handler');
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

---

### More Details

So why does this happen? It has nothing to do with Visual Studio or the debugger. PHP 7 is simply enforcing errors more explicitly than previous versions (i.e <= 5.6). The framework you are using has code not supported by PHP 7 and the errors are not being handled.

Here is something else interesting: https://docs.devsense.com/en/debugging/exceptions